# Good method practice in Java

Tags: java, android, coding-style

In my Android application I have a new intent which is launched depending on the results and returns of some other methods, so I've launched the intent this way:

```
methodOne(methodTwo(methodThree()));
```

This is the code for launch search results:

```
private void methodOne(ArrayList<String> identities) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Class.this, AnotherClass.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("aList", identities);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This currently works fine, and I get the results I want. I just wondered if the way I am calling this method is good or bad practice as I don't really know myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are passing the ArrayList of event identities to the function when you call it, there is no need to do the:

```
eventIdentities = getEventIdentities(searchResults);
```

because you already have the ArrayList being passed into the method so you can use it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, that was a line left prior to altering my code. Is the initial call fine as it is though, there's no assumed bad practice about it?

Comment: It looks good to me. It's not doing any unnecessary computation or anything so I don't see any reason it would be bad practice.